# google Colab shows a spark when typing

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Could someone tell me how to get rid of the spark that Google Colab shows when typing. It also moves the body of the notebook a little bit.
[Video link to google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ny89iHyTc-jJy_z4zHDCx5HwA41qxoWB/view?usp=sharing).

I've had this issue for more than 6 months I think.

Comment: This is an April Fool's feature from a few years ago - to get rid of it, click gear icon in the upper right -> Miscellaneous -> set Power Level to "No Power"

Comment: It is a good feature though, it really motivates me to keep typing!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Tools -> Preferences -> Miscellaneous, you can disable both of these there:

uncheck "Corgi mode"
set "Power level" to "No power"